# windows 10 current desktop isolation

Tags: screenshot, windows-10

1. I have windows 10 RTM
2. I have app that creates desktop screenshots on regular basis
3. I need to launch this app on Desktop1 (it will reside in tray as well)
4. Then start Desktop2 and stay there
5. App should record Desktop1, not Desktop2

In other words I need this app (any app) to record only Desktop where it was launched
Is it possible, any hacks, workarounds?

Comment: A process is already associated with the desktop it was created on.  Have you actually tried this or do you just assume it is a problem?

Comment: I launch app in the first desktop, switch to the second one, app makes screenshot, on screenshot I can see desktop2 instead of desktop1, but I need the app to make desktop1 screenshot while I`m working in desk2. Yes, I tried it. I always get screenshot of the desktop where I`m working at the moment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, windows 10 multiple desktops feature may provide just dependent desktops, for purposes like this it's ok to use sysinternals Desktops app. Checked, works. Thanks

Comment: To anyone else reading this, sysinternals Desktops does not play very nice with Windows 10 (regarding wallpaper switching, etc).  But unfortunately, it is the only solution I have found for getting programs to launch in a background desktop without using separate user accounts.